# Why can't the earth discharge my DC batteries?

Tags: ac, dc

Electrical newbie here. After watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tn7rvhqa2vo) I noticed that in the event of a fault, the AC power in your house can discharge into the earth/ground (which thus causes the house breaker to trip).

If AC power can be discharged into the ground then why can't I drain a standard DC energizer battery by connecting a wire to the positive terminal and placing the wire in the earth/ground?

Comment: Place wires from BOTH terminals into the ground and it will discharge (eventually, if the earth is damp enough)

Comment: @BrianDrummond I've dropped batteries in water before and they don't seem to discharge. They work fine afterwards.

Comment: You didn't wait long enough. Salt water would speed up the process, as my weather station (on the coast) found out one winter.

Answer (score 3):

If the battery negative was also connected to ground, then it would, as it's completing a circuit.

The neutral side of house AC power is connected to ground at some point, either the generation station, the sub station, or the inlet to your house, you just don't see the connection normally. It's there so that if there's a live to chassis fault in your equipment, which would be hazardous, enough current will flow to blow a fuse or trip a breaker.

Answer (score 2):

Current always flows in a closed loop circuit, both polarities of the source have to be connected somehow.

For your AC outlet this works, because the neutral line is grounded at the next transformer station. The moment you connect the AC outlets line voltage to ground you close the loop to the neutral wire via the ground.

A battery on the other hand is floating. If you connect one terminal to ground, there is no connection via this ground to the other terminal of the battery and so there can flow no current.

Answer (score 1):

That's because mains neutral is tied to earth wire at some point in the electrical system, like at your fuse box. So mains neutral is at earth potential and the earth wire is the safety wire. Same thing with car chassis, even if you have separate positive and negative/return wire, you can tie the car cassis to the battery negative terminal.